# Apache VirtualHost redirect, change only domain

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

How can I create VirtualHost to redirect all links changing only its domain, including subdomain and parameters:

```
exampleA.com -> exampleB.com
test.exampleA.com -> test.exampleB.com
test1234.exampleA.com/url/test.html?param=222 -> test1234.exampleB.com/url/test.html?param=222
```

I want to redirect all subdomains like *, and it should be permanent 301

Now I have a simple 301 redirection

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName exampleA.com
        ServerAlias *.exampleA.com

        RewriteEngine On
        Redirect 301 / https://exampleB.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can use the default host (which will be used for ALL hosts except for those where a specific virtual host is defined). In that default host you implement external redirection rules according to your desire. Note: it is always the _first_ defined virtual host that the http server will consider to be the default host.

Answer (score 3):

I have never done something like this, but try the redirect option in your virtualhost file. First enable rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then in your virtualhost file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =exampleA.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.exampleA.com
RewriteRule ^ https://exampleB%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Read more about this here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

It takes the original domain and rewrites to another. In older apache I remember it goes something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain1.com
  Redirect / http://www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think i will redirect only www but I want all subdomains

Comment: but this is the problem I don't know how to write this for all domains like *

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName exampleA.com
        ServerAlias *.exampleA.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+\.)?exampleA\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%1exampleB.com$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```